# How do I use different layouts in Reach Router?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, reach-router

I have an app where I have `N` different layouts (eg. `BeforeLogin`, `MainLayout`, `SomeElseLayout`, etc.).

Each layout is an HTML-markup component that should wrap a page-component, like `Settings`, `Profile`, etc.

I need to be able to assign a specific layout to each of my routes (or a groups of routes).

For instance, I want URLs

```
/register
/info/*
/about
```

... to use `BeforeLogin` layout component (to be children of), and

```
/dashboard
/profile/*
/settings/*
```

...to use `MainLayout`.

Also, some URLs, like `/` might use one layout before user logs-in in and another after. But that, I presume, will be possible to achieve with conditional rendering once the main question is answered.

**So the question is - How do I do that?**

(besides, of course, rendering the layout within each page-component explicitly, I would prefer my components to be layout-agnostic)

Thanks!

P.S. For those who missed, the question is about `Reach router`, not `React Router`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily create multiple [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) where each would represent one of your layout components. Then you'd just wrap component you want with desired layout:

```
const withMainLayout = (Component) => (props) => {
    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <Component {...props} />
        </MainLayout>
    )
}
```

And then you would use it like

```
const LayoutDashboard = withMainLayout(DashboardComponent);
```

This way you can create X layout and corresponding HOC's and then just wrap desired components.

Comment: Thank you! It did solve my problem, though I hoped there is mo elegant way driven by the router. Looks like so far no other options :) Thanks, again!